# Javascript if no hash in URL

Tags: javascript, url

I can show hash in URL with

```
var hash = location.hash.substr(1);

if (hash === "home") {
  $(".pageContent").load("?embed&page=home");
}
```

How can I check if there is no hash in URL like `!isset`?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check if there is no hash in URL like !isset?

```
if (window.location.hash) {
  // Hash exists
} else {
  // Hask doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In this case hash will be an empty string so:

```
if (hash == "")
```

You can check of null and undefined in JS in relation to 'isset' of php:

```
if(hash == undefined)
```